# Update Data frame from another data frame Pandas

Tags: pandas

1. If no changes for the row of DF1 to DF2 for unique code column A then it will no. change.
2. if the value changes in any column of the row of unique code column A of DF2 it will update in DF1.
3. add new rows along with the unique code of column A in DF1

First Dataframe

[image]

Second data frame

[image]

Comment: please edit your post to include the expected output dataframe

Comment: So finally need `df1 = df2.copy()` ? How is update data? In some loop?

Comment: please post your data as a dataframe, dictionary, or raw data, not images.

Comment: data1=[[1,1,1],[2,1,2],[3,1,3],[4,9,0],[5,9,9]]
data2=[[1,1,1],[2,1,2],[3,1,3],[4,9,12],[5,9,19],[6,9,9],[7,9,6],[8,11,12],[9,13,14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['A', 'B','C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['A', 'B','C'])

Comment: i have this type of data having millions rows update local database from server. Some rows are old and some are updated and some are new...kindly suggest to update in loop or chunk